# Definition of certain Gateaux differentials of the norm in E. R. Lorch: "A Curvature Study of Convex Bodies in Banach Spaces"

Tags: derivatives, normed-spaces, banach-spaces, dual-spaces, gateaux-derivative

In the paper [E. R. Lorch: A Curvature Study of Convex Bodies in Banach Spaces](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF02415327.pdf) from 1953, the following assumptions and definitions are stated in section II (p. 107-108):

> Let $(B, \| \cdot \|)$ be a [real Banach space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_space#Definition) and $B^*$ its [dual space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_space#Dual_space).
> Let $r > 1$ and $G(x) := \frac{1}{r} \| x \|^r$ and $\phi(\alpha, \beta) := G(x + \alpha y + \beta z)$, where $x, y, z \in B$ are fixed and $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$.
> Assuming that $\phi$ is twice [continuously differentiable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function), the derivative of $\phi$ with respect to $\alpha$ at $\alpha = \beta = 0$ will be denoted the $G_y(x)$. [...]
> It is clear that $G_x(x) = r G(x)$. [...]
> The second derivatives of $\phi$ at $\alpha = \beta = 0$ will be denoted by $G_{y, y}(x)$, $G_{y, z}(x)$ and $G_{z, z}(x)$. [...] It is clear that $G_{y, z}(x) = G_{z, y}(x)$.

I am trying to understand the functions $G_y$, $G_{y, y}$, $G_{y, z}$ and $G_{z, z}$.
Firstly, we have $G \colon B \to \mathbb{R}$ and $\phi \colon \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$.

I would write
$$
G_y(x)
= \frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha}\bigg|_{\alpha = \beta = 0} \phi(\alpha, \beta)
= \lim_{\gamma \to 0} \frac{\phi(\gamma, 0) - \phi(0, 0)}{\gamma}
= \lim_{\gamma \to 0} \frac{G(x + \gamma y) - G(x)}{\gamma}
= \text{d}G(x; y),
$$
where the last expression is the [Gateaux derivative of $G$ at $x$ in direction $y$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gateaux_derivative#Definition).
This would make sense since we can then verify $G_x(x) = r G(x)$ (which is stated as "clear" above): for $x \in B$ we have
$$
G_x(x)
= \lim_{\gamma \to 0} \frac{G(x + \gamma x) - G(x)}{\gamma}
= G(x) \lim_{\gamma \to 0} \frac{(1 + \gamma)^r - 1}{\gamma}
= r G(x).
$$
Furthermore, $y \mapsto G_y(x)$ is a linear bounded map $B \to \mathbb R$, which seems to be what is stated in theorem 1 ("If $x$ is any fixed element in $B$, then $G_y(x)$ represents a bounded [linear functional](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/linear+functional)").

> How do the corresponding expressions for $G_{y, y}(x)$, $G_{y, z}(x)$ and $G_{z, z}(x)$ look like?
> In particular, are the second derivatives both taken with respect to $\alpha$ or are they mixed?

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gateaux_derivative#Higher_derivatives) gives the following as one definition of the second order Gateaux derivative of $G$:
$$
D^2 G(x)\{y ,z \}
:= \lim_{\gamma \to 0} \frac{\text{d}G(x + \gamma y; z) - \text{d}G(x; z)}{\gamma}
= \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \alpha \partial \beta} \bigg|_{\alpha = \beta= 0} \phi(\alpha, \beta).
$$
Is this expression $G_{y, z}(x)$?

If so, we would presumably have
$$
G_{y, y}(x)
= \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \alpha^2} \phi(\alpha, \beta) \bigg|_{\alpha = \beta = 0}
= \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \alpha^2} G(x + \alpha y + \beta z) \bigg|_{\alpha = \beta = 0}
= \lim_{\gamma \to 0} \frac{\text{d}G(x + \gamma y; y) - \text{d}G(x; y)}{\gamma}
$$
and analogously
$$
G_{z, z}(x)
= \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \beta^2} \phi(\alpha, \beta) \bigg|_{\alpha = \beta = 0}
= \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \beta^2} G(x + \alpha y + \beta z) \bigg|_{\alpha = \beta = 0}.
$$

> According to Theorem 2 in that paper, we have $G_{y, z}(x) \in B^*$ for $y \in B$ and $G_y(x) \in B^*$ for $x \in B$.
> Do my above guesses about $G_{y, y}$, ... fulfill those requirements?